# Better word for "massively-multidirectional"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

The print and broadcast media (radio and television) are only capable of transmitting information in one direction, *from* the transmitting node (the printing press, the broadcast tower) *to* the receiving node (the newspaper, the TV).

On the medium of the internet, there is no transmitter/receiver dichotomy - information can flow *to* any node just as easily as it can flow *from* it.

If you were trying to describe **the conversation** taking place over these mediums on the macro-level, what word would you use to describe these different paradigms?

For instance, I've been saying that the internet inherently capacitates a "massively-multidirectional" conversational paradigm while the print and broadcast media can only capacitate a unidirectional conversational paradigm -- but I'm looking for a better terminology - I don't think these terms fully grasp the dichotomy I'm trying to describe.

Comment: While omnidirectional emphasizes the direction, I personally prefer either *cooperative* or *collaborative* since it reflects the true nature of the Internet. Besides, they both imply the massive and multi-directional qualities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from microphones:  **Omnidirectional**.

Answer (score 0):

How about: **Isotropic homogenous** ?

It's frequently used in physics to describe an interaction that is "fair" in all directions regardless of which point you pick

If you want to convey that the same thing happens in the reverse direction then maybe these words are needed:

- **mutual**
- **symmetric**

Comment: Hmm - what about just "isotropic"? I'm drawn to this term, but I'm not comfortable enough with its usage to know whether it's correct here. Would it be inaccurate?

Answer (score 0):

If *direction* is really what you're focussing on then I like @fuzzyanalysis' suggestion of *omnidirectional*.

You could also focus on the distinct, *conversational* nature of the Internet compared to television and newspaper.  It is an **interactive** medium.  It is also **decentralized** and relatively **unmoderated**, unlike the old media.

I hope you find some value in one of those words.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder if the poster will return to comment :S